# Invalid char in inputstream

Tags: java, character-encoding, inputstream

I am reading a stream from a HttpURLConnection to a String that will passed to a SAXParser.

The content looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

_

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( con.getInputStream(),  StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(output);
}
```

When I try to print it to console, I see

```
?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

(invalid char at the beginning) Saxparser fails to deal with that.

If I debug, and hover above the String var with the mouse, I see it correctly.

Comment: Are you sure it's in UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `?` is `byte-order mark`. The `mark/reset` method of `BufferedReader` can used to check and skip first char if it's BOM.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( con.getInputStream(),  StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
br.mark(256);
char firstChar = br.read();
System.err.println(Integer.toString(firstChar));//for debug
if (firstChar != 0xFEFF) {//char of BOM
    br.reset();
}
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(output);
}
```